# calling function on same member yields different result using access function vs using member function

Tags: c++, function, reference, member

I'm accessing member data, mslc, 1) by reference using an access function, and 2) directly using another member function. I display the contents of the member data, a bitset, and it's showing different depending on which method I use. It shouldn't be this way, since I'm accessing the same member data each time. What am I missing? Here's the output:

member slc:
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
res:
Here's mslc:
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0

The two bit patterns should be the same. They should be the first one.

```
class Tdoh // contains a bitset - includes other things not at issue here
{
private:
    Tpiz mslc; // the bitset
public:
    Tpiz& get_mslc();
    int res(); // displays the mslc bit pattern
};
Tpiz& Tdoh::get_mslc()
{
    return mslc;
}
void Tdoh::res()
{
    cout << "Here's mslc:" << endl;

    for(int m=0;m<=11;m++)
    {
        cout << mslc.get_setPiz_elem(m) << " "; // show bit pattern of member mslc
    }
    cout << endl;
}
class Tpiz
{
    private:
        bitset<12> setPiz;
    public:
        void set_setPat(bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool); // sets the bit pattern
        bool get_setPiz_elem(int) const; // gets the designated bit
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Tdoh doh; // object contains a member bitset
    Tpiz temp2_piz; // a separate bitset
    temp2_piz = doh.get_mslc(); // get a reference to the object's member bitset
    temp2_piz.set_setPat(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); // set the member bitset's pattern
    cout << "member slc:" << endl;
    for(int j=0;j<=11;j++)
    {
        cout << temp2_piz.get_setPiz_elem(j) << " "; // display the member bitset's pattern
    }
    cout << endl; 
    cout << "res:" << endl; 
    cout << doh.res() << endl; // see function code. It accesses member bitset directly and displays pattern, but 
    // in this case the pattern is wrong because it's not the pattern 010000000000 that was set above. Instead, it's a
    // different, default pattern set when a Tpiz is created, before it is set by something like set_setPat(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0).
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `temp2_piz = doh.get_mslc(); // get a reference to the object's member bitset` <-- Yes, `doh.get_mslc()` returns a reference -- but then you copy the referent into `temp2_piz`, which has no connection to the original `Tpiz` object. So you are displaying the state of two independent bit sets.  Try `Tpiz &temp2_piz = doh.get_mslc();`.

Comment: The return types of `Tdoh::res` is different in declaration and definition. That code should result in compiler error.

Comment: cdhowie, thanks. I knew it was going to be something basic. I'm new to using references.

Comment: R Sahu, my typo. Return type should be void.